# Walk in dict to find desired keys

Tags: python, dictionary

I am able to recursively obtain the values of all keys in a particular node where the key is `extras`:

```
def findkeys(node, kv):
    if isinstance(node, list):
        for i in node:
            for x in findkeys(i, kv):
                yield x
    elif isinstance(node, dict):
        if kv in node:
            yield node[kv]
        for j in node.values():
            for x in findkeys(j, kv):
                yield x
```

With following input:

```
a = {'product': {'extras': {'size': 'large', 'color': 'green', 'name':'shirt'}, 'cat': 'male', 'season': 'summer'}, 'id': 'a12b', 'brand': 'aua'}
print(list(findkeys(a, 'extras')))
```

the output is as desired:

> [{'size': 'large', 'color': 'green', 'name': 'shirt'}]

However, how can I change my function to, additionally, capture `cat` and `id`? Note that I **only** want to capture the sibling key cat of extras and the parent key id of extras. For me, an optimal output should be:

> [{'size': 'large', 'color': 'green', 'name': 'shirt', 'cat': 'male', 'id': 'a12b' }]

Also note that `product` may not be present in the dict. This is the reason why I need to find extras first (which is always present) and search in their siblings and parents

As suggested in the comments, please find attached a complete dictionary with possible cases:

```
{  
   "contents":[  
      {  
         "product":{  
            "extras":{  
               "size":"large",
               "color":"green",
               "name":"shirt"
            },
            "cat":"male"
         },
         "id":"a12b"
      },
      {  
         "products":{  
            "extras":{  
               "size":"small",
               "color":"red",
               "name":"trouser"
            },
            "cat":"male",
            "price":12.21
         },
         "id":"a23b"
      },
      {  
         "produkt":{  
            "extras":{  
               "size":"medium",
               "color":"yellow",
               "name":"hat"
            },
            "cat":"female",
            "price":2.87,
            "units":100
         },
         "id":"a34b"
      }
   ]
}
```

Please note that I cannot just use ['product'] to navigate in the objects, as product may not be present (other variations may appear). That comes this way from the data source. My desired output:

```
[{'size': 'large', 'color': 'green', 'name': 'shirt', 'cat': 'male', 'id': 'a12b' },
{'size': 'small', 'color': 'red', 'name': 'trouser', 'cat': 'male', 'id': 'a23b' },
{'size': 'medium', 'color': 'yellow','name': 'hat', 'cat': 'female', 'id': 'a34b' }]
```

Comment: such logic does not seem consistent: capture sibling keys + keys on parent level OR  parent level**s** ? pretty arbitrary

Comment: well, `cat` * is on the same level as extras here. they are both keys inside `product`. You may want to think of a better input example, that also showcases what you want to *exclude* edit: ack, i can't even keep the key levels straight here.

Comment: I agree with @RomanPerekhrest.  Your problem is ill-defined.  Specifically, you say that "I do not just want to get all keys sharing the same level of extras or product."  However, you *do* want to get "id", which is on the same level of "product".  Also, you *do* want to get "cat", which is on the same level of "extras" What is the criterion to distinguish between "cat" and other elements on the same level as "extras"?

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I know, explanation was not optimal, neither is the data source :). I just tried to use the minimal possible example. I have edited the question  and hope it is much more clear now.

Comment: As @RomanPerekhrest said, your problem can't be solved. A python dictionary isn't an ordered structure, thus a "sibling" key isn't  a valid concept. In your example, the "cat" key isn't closer to "extras" than "season" is. You'd need more information, such as lists used to order your keys, for example : ["extras", "cat", "season"]

Comment: Your example data should contain at least one item (preferably two) that would not be selected. Otherwise, it is very difficult to figure out the pattern you're working with and we won't be able to help you much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not thoroughly tested, just base on your current function and added a mutable argument to store the values:

```
def findkeys(node, kv, data={}):
    if isinstance(node, list):
        for i in node:
            for x in findkeys(i, kv):
                yield x
    elif isinstance(node, dict):
        id = node.get("id")
        if id:
            data["id"] = id
        if kv in node:
            data["cat"] = node.get("cat")
            data.update(node[kv])
            yield data
            data.clear()
        for j in node.values():
            for x in findkeys(j, kv):
                yield x

for i in findkeys(b["contents"], 'extras'):
    print (i)
```

Result:

```
{'id': 'a12b', 'cat': 'male', 'size': 'large', 'color': 'green', 'name': 'shirt'}
{'id': 'a23b', 'cat': 'male', 'size': 'small', 'color': 'red', 'name': 'trouser'}
{'id': 'a34b', 'cat': 'female', 'size': 'medium', 'color': 'yellow', 'name': 'hat'}
```

Answer (score 0):

'cat' is a sibling of the item you're looking for but 'id' is an "uncle".  Your recursive function would need pass itself the "path" of sub-dictionaries that it went through so that you can backtrack to the parent and grand parent of the key you find.